# Parsing Json in Filemaker iteration overwrite

Tags: json, parsing, iteration, record, filemaker

I copied this json parsing script from here: https://fmhelp.filemaker.com/help/16/fmp/en/index.html#page/FMP_Help/json-functions.html#ww1155222

filemaker json parsing script:

```
Set Variable [ $ProductCount ; Value:
   ValueCount (
      JSONListKeys ( $$JSON ; "bakery.product" )
   ) ]
Set Variable [ $i; Value: 0 ]
If [ $ProductCount > 0 ]
   Loop
      New Record/Request
      Set Field [ Products::ID ;
         JSONGetElement ( $$JSON ; "bakery.product[" & $i & "]id" ) ]
      Set Field [ Products::Price ;
         JSONGetElement ( $$JSON ; "bakery.product[" & $i & "]price" ) ]
      Set Field [ Products::Stock ;
         JSONGetElement ( $$JSON ; "bakery.product[" & $i & "]stock" ) ]
      Commit Records/Requests [ With dialog: Off ]
      Set Variable [ $i ; Value: $i + 1 ]
      Exit Loop If [ $i ≥ $ProductCount ]
   End Loop
End If
```

When I use the script debugger and dataviewer and go through my script step by step it works like it's supposed to until it gets to the end of the script. Once the script has been completed it sets all of my id fields in each record to the last id field that it ran. I can't figure out how to parse my data and keep it separated in different records.

Here is my script:

```
Insert from URL [ Select; with dialog: Off ; $json; "web address"]    
Set Variable [ $grievanceCount ; Value:
       ValueCount (
          JSONListKeys ( $json ; "submissions" )
       ) ]
    Set Variable [ $i; Value: 0 ]
    If [ $grievanceCount > 0 ]
       Loop
          New Record/Request
          Set Field [ grievanceSubmissions::ID ;
             JSONGetElement ( $json ; "submissions[" & $i & "]id" ) ]
   Commit Records/Requests [ With dialog: Off ]
          Set Variable [ $i ; Value: $i + 1 ]
          Exit Loop If [ $i ≥ $grievanceCount ]
       End Loop
    End If
```

JSON:

{"submissions":[{"id":"383694318","timestamp":"2018-02-09 15:23:45","user_agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:58.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/58.0","remote_addr":"1.1.1.1","payment_status":"","latitude":"0","longitude":"0","read":"1"},{"id":"397263244","timestamp":"2018-04-02 11:02:53","user_agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 11_2_6 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/604.5.6 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/11.0 Mobile/15D100 Safari/604.1","remote_addr":"1.1.1.1","payment_status":"","latitude":"0","longitude":"0","read":"1"},{"id":"397578480","timestamp":"2018-04-03 12:23:12","user_agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 7.0; SAMSUNG SM-G935A Build/NRD90M) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) SamsungBrowser/6.4 Chrome/56.0.2924.87 Mobile Safari/537.36","remote_addr":"1.1.1.1","payment_status":"","latitude":"0","longitude":"0","read":"0"}],"total":3,"pages":1,"pretty_field_id":"59493345"}

Comment: Are you sure the id’s actually are different in the source? Are there any auto enter options on the id field? Would be helpful to see the json source.

Comment: I feel like an idiot. I had my GrievanceID field set to global. I'm not sure why that would keep the data from being saved the correct way though.

Comment: Global means one value for all records, so that’s why. You’re not the first to have done that :)